# I can't pass Blargss's test rom for sound

Tags: emulation, gameboy

I'm working on my own GameBoy emulator, just for learning.

And I having problems passing the Blargg's test ROM.

I'm following the Pan docs but I can't find relevant information to pass the tests.

How are the rules for write and read registers so I can pass the 01-registers.rom for the dmg sound?